# program has stopped working?How to have int array size exceeding 1,000,000?

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

assignment: write a c++ program on sieve of eratosthenes and print out all the prime numbers between 1 and 1,000,000.
I've realized that when I have a really large number such as 1,000,000, the program stops working and for small numbers such as 9,000, the program works perfectly fine. Is there a way to have 1,000,000 as integer array size?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sieve(int [], int num);

int main()
{
    int numOfElements;
    cout<<"please input number"<<endl;
    cin>>numOfElements;
    int primeArray[numOfElements];
    sieve(primeArray, numOfElements);
    return 0;
}

//prime number: any whole number greater than one and has factors of only the number itself and one.
void sieve(int prime[], int num){
    int i,j;
    for(int a=0;a<num;a++){
        prime[a]=a+1;
    }
    prime[0]=0;//we know 1 is not a prime;
    for(i=2;i<=num;i++){
        if(prime[i-1]!=0){
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }
        for(j=i*i;j<=num;j+=i){
            prime[j-1]=0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, if you're working with large numbers, you may need to use `long` or `unsigned long` instead of `int`

Comment: If you need to use an array instead of a vector use `int * primeArray = new int[numOfElements];` to use the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If you need an array, then use a vector. You can call `data()` to access the array if you really need it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes you can do that but I know sometimes people are not allowed to use things from the STL.  I know a lot of instructors that don't let you use the STL on homework until almost the end of the class.

Comment: @NathanOliver: We answer questions about C++, not about arbitrary constrained subsets of the language!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Good to know.  I will keep that in mind when giving answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm half-trolling. The truth is you're unavoidably right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being able to write `int primeArray[numOfElements];` (this is called a variable length array) is a *compiler extension*: not part of standard C++. I do hope your compiler is warning you about this; if not then make sure the warning level is set correctly.

But that's a moot point in this case: attempting to allocate such a large array *on the stack* will fail. Stack sizes are limited to a size of an order of magnitude of a megabyte.

The best remedy is to use a `std::vector` which (i) is standard C++, and (ii) will allocate the memory on the *heap*.

If you *must* use an array, then you can use `int* primeArray = new int[numOfElements]`. Don't forget to free the memory using `delete[]`, noting the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

```
int primeArray[numOfElements];
```

This is wrong!
Array dimensions must be known at compile-time.
They must be compile-time constants.

Use a `std::vector<int>` instead.